# Using Content Picker Field Tokens in Projection Layout

Tags: orchardcms

I'm attempting to rewrite the output of a projection.  This projection will be rendering items that have the Content Picker field.  I would like to include a link to the selected content item.  It seems I should be able to use tokens to rewrite the output of a property in my layout, but I can't find the magical incantation necessary.

It seems the Content Picker provides a token to get the selected content, but I'm not sure how to use it. Also, I'm not really familiar with how to chain token calls so I can then get the display url.

The variations I'm trying have returned nothing.  Anyone know how this is done?

Comment: Did you watch this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka55wTTXZg8 I think I showed how to do that in there.

Comment: Yep, actually I'm in that video, haha.  Here's what I'm trying that seems like it should work, but it's not...  {Content.Fields.MyContentType.MyContentPickerFieldName.Content.DisplayUrl}

Comment: You're right, this looks like it should work. Can you please file a bug?

Comment: Here is a link to the issue for reference: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19524